# Receiving entities from a many to many relation with Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a two entities:

Call entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *        name="calls",
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repositories\CallRepository")
 */
class Call implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Many Calls have Many Tags.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="taggedCalls", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    public $tags;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    public $phone;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $call = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'tags' => [],
        ];

        foreach ($this->tags as $tag) {
            $author['books'][] = $tag->jsonSerialize();
        }

        return $call;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection|Tag[]
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addNewTag($tag)
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag)) return;
        $this->tags[] = $tag;
    }

}
```

Tag Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tags",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="tag_value", columns={"value"})})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Tag implements \JsonSerializable
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120, nullable=false)
     */
    public $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Call", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="calls_tags",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="call_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $taggedCalls;


    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }


    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'value' => $this->value,
        ];
    }
}
```

And the REST controller which serves to receive an array of `Call` entities with the corresponding array of tags:

```
   /**
 * @Route("/calls", name="my_v1_calls")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function calls(Request $request)
{
    $this->recordLog($request);
    $user = $this->authorizeUser($request);

    $qb = $this->callRepository->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->where("c.user = :user")->setParameter("user", $user);

    $limit = $request->query->get("limit", 500);
    if ($limit < 1 || $limit > 500)
        $limit = 500;

    $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

    $calls = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    $serializedCalls = [];
    foreach ($calls as $call) {
        $serializedCalls[] = $call->jsonSerialize();
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'calls' => $serializedCalls
    ));
}
```

The table joining works fine: adding new tags creates valid relations inside calls_tags table. But I am unable to receive tags for the corresponding call: the controller's code snippet shown above returns empty array of tags for each of the calls even though the data in datatable exists and valid. Am I missing something?

Comment: You forgot the most important part - your query.

Comment: Your comment assumes that I have to manually write additional query for receiving tags? Well, I thought that it is done in the background, once main entity (in my case Call entity) is fetched. For what else mapping annotations (e.g. fetch=Eager) are?

Comment: My comment assumes nothing. It means that the problem is in your query, which you replaced with humble "Here my query goes".

Comment: >For what else mapping annotations (e.g. fetch=Eager) are?
There are a dozen of guys who know how it works, sometimes they even answer on SO, but I am not one of them.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the `fetch=EAGER` in the annotation is only adhered to when Doctrine does the querying, e.g. when using `find()` on the repository. Since you build your own query you have to join tags. The idea is, that when you write your own query as DQL or via QueryBuilder you want to specifically instruct Doctrine to do something, effectively overwriting the default you set in the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

What you suppose this part of code would do?

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    $call = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'phone' => $this->phone,
        'tags' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($this->tags as $tag) {
→       $author['books'][] = $tag->jsonSerialize();
    }

    return $call;
}
```

If associated entity implements `JsonSerializable`, you can simply do this:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'phone' => $this->phone,
        'tags' => $this->tags->toArray(),
    ];
}
```